# Nuke Build declare a tool that is fetched as part of the build

Tags: nuke-build

Most of the tools I use, are dotnet tools that are referenced from csproj file and automagically fetched by nuget.
A few tools are old-school Framework tools, which should be copied into the tools directory before use.
For the latter I have a GetTools Target.

My problem is declaring the Tool:

```
 [LocalExecutable("./tools/MyFrameworkTool.exe")] 
 readonly Tool FrameworkTool;
```

This throws the following assertion:

```
Assertion failed: File.Exists(C:\Jenkins\workspace\Job\./tools/MyFrameworkTool.exe)
```

And the FrameworkTool is null.

How can I make a 'late' declaration of the tool, when it has been fetched by the GetTools Target?

Comment: what is a framework tool?

Comment: @Matthias dotnet framework (4.6.1) as opposed to dotnet core. Which cannot be installed with the 'dotnet tool install' command.

Comment: And which tool in particular? how do you install it?

Comment: It's a self built tool that must access an MS Access database, and thus cannot be net core. We just copy it in from a network share.

Comment: You can’t use the attribute if the tool is not available at build start already. If you want to initialize the field in a target, you can use `ToolResolver`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For other developers in the same situation, I post the answer here.

Matthias suggestion to use ToolResolver was the key.

The initial (Restore) Target can copy the tool to the ./tools/MyCustomTool directory.

With the ToolResolver static class, one can declare it in the Target, where it is referenced:

```
Tool MyCustomTool = ToolResolver.GetLocalTool("./tools/MyCustomTool/MyCustomTool.exe");
```

MyCustomTool is now available to use inside this Target.